# How to make a button that toggles between divs when clicked?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a button that toggles the div to invisible or visible whenever pressed. However, the button doesn't work. I thought it could maybe be because of the button being in another component than the targeted component, but I don't really know.

The toggle bar with the button html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row toggleBar">
          <button (click)="isDisplay" class="btn btn-toggleBtn">  Keyboard View</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

The toggle bar ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle-bar',
  templateUrl: './toggle-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toggle-bar.component.css']
})
export class ToggleBarComponent implements OnInit {
  isDisplay = false;
  
  toggleDisplay(){
    this.isDisplay = !this.isDisplay;
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The app component html file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" style="padding-left: unset; padding-right: unset;">
      <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-8">
          <app-toggle-bar></app-toggle-bar>
          <div [hidden]="isDisplay" class="touchView">
            <app-touch-view></app-touch-view>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4  checkout">
        <app-checkout></app-checkout>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output your toggle bar component display status to get its value in app component, your current implementation is missing that part, `isDisplay` toggle value is not triggering in app its always the default what it set in app.

toggle bar component

```
export class ToggleBarComponent implements OnInit {
 isDisplay = false;

 @Output() showHide: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

 toggleDisplay(){
  this.isDisplay = !this.isDisplay;
  this.showHide.emit(this.isDisplay)
 }
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }

}
```

in app template add output method to get emitted value

```
  <div class="col-8">
      <app-toggle-bar (showHide)=onShowHide($event)></app-toggle-bar>
      <div [hidden]="isDisplay" class="touchView">
        <app-touch-view></app-touch-view>
      </div>
  </div>
```

in app component set isDisplay status by emitted output from toggle bar component.

```
onShowHide(value) {
 this.isDisplay = value
}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in the child component to send events to the parent component. It could then be bound to in the parent to set the display state of other elements.

Try the following

Child component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle-bar',
  templateUrl: './toggle-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toggle-bar.component.css']
})
export class ToggleBarComponent implements OnInit {
  isDisplay = true;
  @Output() display = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Child template

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row toggleBar">
    <!-- toggle boolean flag and emit in `click` handler -->
    <button (click)="isDisplay=!isDisplay;display.emit(isDisplay)" class="btn btn-toggleBtn">  
      Keyboard View
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent component

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isDisplay = true;       // <-- default value (hidden)
  ...
}
```

Parent template

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" style="padding-left: unset; padding-right: unset;">
      <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <!-- assign the event (`true` or `false`) in the event handler -->
      <app-toggle-bar (display)="isDisplay=$event"></app-toggle-bar>     
      <div [hidden]="isDisplay" class="touchView">
        <app-touch-view></app-touch-view>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  checkout">
      <app-checkout></app-checkout>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```